# android service logging sensor data uninterrupted

Tags: java, android, service, wakelock

I'm trying to write a service for an android app that monitors at a fixed sampling rate **continuously** the accelerometer sensor values. Below is a snippet of the code that I'm using to keep the service running.

```java
public class MyService extends Service {
    ...
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(mainIntent);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setContentText(TAG)
            .build();
        context.startForeground(1, notification);
        PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
        PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "MyWakelockTag");
        wakeLock.acquire();
        //Register Accelerometer Sensor Listener Here
        return START_STICKY;
}
```

When the device is running on batteries after some minutes it goes to sleep. The service will be restarted sporadically, but with no consistency. The ideas that I'm considering right now are:

- [Running as system service](http://www.programering.com/a/MTMxMTNwATk.html)
- [Exploring the Google Fit API](https://developers.google.com/fit/overview)

But I wish it wasn't necessary. Does anyone know a way to achieve this sensor logging feature to run always?

--

I also tried changing the sensor listener for a plain repeating thread in case it was only the sensor the one going to sleep, but the effect was the same. I believe it's only related to power management of android

I'm aware of the energy efficiency implications of this, but it is necessary for this application to guarantee that the logging is uninterrupted and at high sampling rate.

EDITED: Changed title to clarify

**UPDATE**: Converting it to a [persistent system application](http://devescape.blogspot.com/2011/02/persistent-services-in-android.html) doesn't help

Comment: There is no such thing as an unkillable service, a user can always shut it down completely if he wants

Comment: it doesn't have to be a service, this is part of a research project and I just need it to log the sensor data at all times on my device. If there is an  element other than a service that will achieve this I would use it, but I'm unaware of such a thing.
It's fine if the user kills it, but I just don't want the OS to kill it

Comment: The OS *will* kill any of your app components eventually. Best you can do is restart it after, like you do with START_STICKY. I don't know of a better way than a sticky service

Comment: It would be fine if the service would be restarted immediately after being killed, but if I need to register the data at 20 [Hz] it's unacceptable for me to have periods of over 120 seconds without data which is what is happening. I get no consistency

Comment: You can't know how long it will take before it's restarted. Often it will be relatively quick (seconds/minutes) but sometimes it will take longer. 120 seconds is a pretty risky limit. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36188851/android-start-redeliver-intent-takes-a-long-time-hours-to-restart-service

Comment: yes, that's exactly what I need to solve and what I have come here to ask :) I need to be able to guarantee that part of the app will stay running always or my data collection will be worthless and right now I'm not sure how to achieve this

Comment: I don't think that's possible. If you find a solution, please ping me so I can learn it too :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this. Actually it was an error in the code. The WakeLock in the snippet I posted is a local variable and gets garbage collected when the function returns, so there wasn't actually a lock. I fixed it by changing this:

```java
public class MyService extends Service {
    private PowerManager powerManager;
    private static PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock;
    ...
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        ...
        powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
        wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "MyWakelockTag");
        wakeLock.acquire();
        ...
}
```